# Transferring XML file to iOS app

Tags: ios, macos

I have an app, in development, that requires an XML file. The app works well in the simulator. However, it fails on an actual device because there is no file. How do I make that file part of the package?

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *directoryPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *directoryPath = [directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/games.xml", directoryPath];
NSLog(@"%@", path);
if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    self.games = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"Found %lu games on device.", (unsigned long)self.games.count);
} else {
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/philHuffman/dev/Games.xml"];
    [fm createFileAtPath:path contents:data attributes:nil];
    self.games = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"Found %lu games in file on the mac.", (unsigned long)self.games.count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just drag the xml file in your project explorer and it will be part of the package when you run/install it

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought too, but I must be missing something, because I still can't get to the file.

Comment: Mind posting the code? Maybe youre doing something wrong with how you access the file?